# Nativescript iOS delegate listView (lazy loading ?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, nativescript

I would like to use the onScroll event on a listview in nativescript but the event does not exist. So I go through the native, so I would like to create a delegate for my listview. Everything works but I do not know why, I have to make a console.log my delegate to use it, otherwise it does not run. Do you have an idea of ​​the reason?

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   items: Array<Item>;

   @ViewChild('header') header: ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('listView') listView: ElementRef;

   // This pattern makes use of Angular’s dependency injection implementation to
   // inject an instance of the ItemService service into this class.
   // Angular knows about this service because it is included in your app’s main NgModule,
   // defined in app.module.ts.
   constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private zone: NgZone) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
       this.items = this.itemService.getItems();
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       setTimeout(() => {
          if (isIOS) {
               let newDelegate = newUITableViewDelegateImpl.initWithOriginalDelegate(this.listView.nativeElement._delegate);
               this.listView.nativeElement.ios.delegate = newDelegate;
               console.log(this.listView.nativeElement.ios.delegate);
           }
       }, 50)

   }
}


class newUITableViewDelegateImpl extends NSObject implements UITableViewDelegate {
    public static ObjCProtocols = [UITableViewDelegate];

    private _originalDelegate: UITableViewDelegate;

    public static initWithOriginalDelegate(originalDelegate: UITableViewDelegate): newUITableViewDelegateImpl {
        console.log("initWithOwner")

        let delegate = <newUITableViewDelegateImpl>newUITableViewDelegateImpl.new();
        delegate._originalDelegate = originalDelegate;

        return delegate;
    }

    public scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        console.log("scrollViewWillBeginDragging");
    }
    public scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        console.log("scrollViewDidScroll");

    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to save the JS reference of `newDelegate` somewhere, otherwise it might be marked for garbage collection. Moreover I would suggest using [RadListView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/load-on-demand) for lazy loading as it has specific events for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, that's it ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to save the JS reference of `newDelegate` somewhere, otherwise it might be marked for garbage collection.

Moreover I would suggest using [RadListView](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/load-on-demand) for lazy loading as it has specific events for that purpose.